# Converting miRNA names to miRBase version IDs

Tags: r, python, bioconductor, computational-biochemistry

I have a list of miRNAs IDs (2000-2500) that I want to find miRBase IDs for them. For example:

hsa-miR-106a ---> hsa-miR-106a-5p
hsa-miR-373* --> hsa-miR-373-5p
hsa-miR-33 --> hsa-miR-33a-5p
I used many R packages and websites such as (miRBaseConverter, miRNAmeConverter, MiEAA, miRSystem,miRandola) but non of them give me the comprehensive result.

e.g. For "hsa-mir-30c-1" miRNAmeConverter did not give miRBase ID but if you search it in miRBase it hsa two matures IDs: hsa-miR-30c-5p & hsa-miR-30c-1-3p.

miRBAseConverter is also like the mentioned one: It can not find the mature one for many miRNAs e.g. "hsa-mir-34" has to mature IDs: "hsa-miR-34a-5p" & "hsa-miR-34a-3p" but despite having them miRBaseConverter could not retrieve them.
[image]

Can anyone suggest any tools that might help to do this?